# While Loop how to?

Tags: c++

I have a test in a couple of days and I was reviewing the study guide and I came across a question that I wasn't familiar with. It says "Write a while loop that continuously loops until the user inputs a number saved in a variable named myNum between -1 and -100. Use only < and > operators." Can someone give me a clear explanation of what exactly I am supposed to do for this question?

Comment: Well. You have to write a while loop...

Comment: I posted an answer, but not sure if its correct because the wording of the question isn't super exact.  Tell me, is this your first C++ class?  I'm only asking because it will help me better understand the scope of what your professor is probably asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not entirely sure what this question is asking, because it seems a bit ambiguous in the wording, but this is what I would assume they are asking for.  I'm not sure how you could get this done with "only" `>` and `<` operators, as you need input and possibly output operators (`>>` and `<<` respectively).  Anyway, I hope that this helps, and if its not perfectly correct with what your assignment is, maybe you can see the logic and make the small changes to have it fit better.

I commented each line, even the obvious (which is sort of a no-no when you get into heavier coding), this way all the syntax makes sense.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Initialize myNum to 1 so that it passes into while-loop
    int myNum = 1;

    // Continue looping as long if number is less than -100 or greater than -1 (terminating the loop when numbers from -100 to -1 are entered)
    while((myNum > -1) || (myNum < -100))
    {
        // Display "Enter Text" to console
        cout << "Enter number: ";

        // Allow user to input number
        cin >> myNum;
    }
}
```